# How to only re-render a nested text value in a list of components in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I want to improve the performance of my render cycle. Assume the following:

**Components**

I have two components, a parent component, and a child component. I am passing two props from the parent component to the child component (`propA` and `propB`). The child component is filled with a list of sets of other components, like this:

```jsx
<View>
    {/*SET 1/*}
    <ComponentA>
        <Component B />
        <Component C />
        <Text>Some Text from data</Text>
        <Component D />
    </ ComponentA>

    {/*SET 2/*}
    <ComponentA>
        <Component B />
        <Component C />
        <Text>Some Text from data</Text>
        <Component D />
    </ ComponentA>

    {/*SET 3/*}
    <ComponentA>...
...
</ View>
```

The number of sets included in the child component depends on the number of data entries which are retrieved from a redux store and updated with a dispatcher:

```
const curData = useSelector(state => state.userData);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const updateData = useCallback((id) => {
    dispatch(updateAttr(id))
}, [dispatch]);
```

Each component set is stored in an array which is created by iterating through the data and managed with a `useState` hook:

```
const [componentSets, setComponentSets] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const newComponentSets = [];

    for (const [i, v] of curData.entries()) {

        updateData(v.id)

        newComponentSets.push(
            <ComponentA 
                attr1={} 
                attr2={} ...>

                <Component B 
                    attr1={} 
                    attr2={} .../>

                <Component C 
                    attr1={} 
                    attr2={} ... />

                <Text 
                    attr1={} 
                    attr2={} ...>Some Text from data</Text>

                <Component D 
                    attr1={} 
                    attr2={} ... />
            </ ComponentA>
        )
    }

    setComponentSets(newComponentSets);
}, [props.propA, props.propB])
```

It is then included in the `return` statement of the child component:

```
return(
    <View>    
        {componentSets.map(x => x)}
    </View>
)
```

**Render Logic**

Currently, as you can see I rerender the whole child component whenever `props.propA` or `props.propB` changes. However, in the case of `props.propA`, only the text value inside the `<Text>` component must change, but the rest should be untouched. In case of changes in `props.propB` a whole set must be updated, based on the `id` attribute of the data.

**Question**

I tried around using the `useMemo()` hook storing the text component in it, but could not achieve what I needed.

**How can I get the rendering logic described above?**

Comment: Are your `propA` and `propB` props independent or dependent of one another?

Comment: @DrewReese They are independent of one another.

Comment: My apologies, the question may have been unclearly phrased, it's not a yes or no question. Is one dependent on the other?

Comment: @Drew Reese, just edited my answer before you send me the comment :) Saw it that my reply did not make sense